# Help designing non-mandatory but crucial fields for user input regarding allergy

Tags: user-behavior, input, input-fields

I have a field that takes user input about allergies to various food etc. This field can not be made mandatory since not everyone is allergic, and therefore should not be forced to fill this field. Whats the best approach to make sure that the user inputs his/hers allergies into this field? Example input could look something like this:

Name: John Doe
Allergies: Peanuts, Lactose, Cheese

Comment: Can you use a mandatory radio button to ask if the user has an allergy and display a text field when the user clicks "yes"? This is one more click for the user, though.

Comment: @chaosflaws I see i left some information out that might be crucial.

The way the page works is like this


 
`[number of people with lactose intolerance] 
[number of people with celiac intolerance]
[number of people who suffer from diabetes (and cant eat sugar)]

number of people with combo / other  allergies [______3] <-textfield
[button for adding x panels that takes the persons name and allergies]`

Comment: @Aron please update your question with relevant details

Comment: Explain to users why do you need this info, how they will benefit from it, etc. See [GoodUI on it](http://goodui.org/#68). This is also private info, so inform, it will be never shared.

Answer (score 2):

You could have a mandatory Radio button so that people can answer a question similar to

*"Do you have any allergies?"*

- No
- Yes

If they select No, they can move on to the next entry. **If they select Yes**, make a **Text Field** go visible so that they could input their Allergies.